# mailchimp - how to add default value for date field?

Tags: mailchimp

I want add a date field into Mailchimp with default value

name: gen
type: date
value: 2019-01-01

[The instructions do not explain how to do it](https://mailchimp.com/help/manage-list-and-signup-form-fields/)

I tried this values:
01/01/2019
2019-01-01

but when new user subrscribes to list,
i don't see any default value

Answer (score 0):

Per [documentation](https://mailchimp.com/help/set-default-merge-values-for-a-list/), "Default merge tag values will only display in campaigns, and not in your list fields."